# Django If statement not working in template

Tags: python, django

i am adding this code to my template while using the django authetication system (USER) and the entry is a model with the entry_author field but its still didnt show me the resulr

```
{% if user.username == entry.entry_author %}
  <p class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Delete Post &rarr;</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have model like below:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
     entry_author = models.ForeignKey(User...)
```

what you should do is:

```
{% if request.user == entry.entry_author %}
```

Also you might want to add another layer of if statement to verify the `request.user` is authenticated.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
     {% if request.user == entry.entry_author %}
```